# Calling Jquery From Servlet

Tags: jquery, servlets

i want to call some jquery functions from the servlet itself. is there any way to call jquery from servlet without using JSP, HTML and other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP pages and documents are converted to servlets which are then compiled into bytecode and executed on the server. The output of the servlet is sent as a response to a browser which attempts to render it into an HTML page. The HTML page could include jQuery code.

If you want to call a servlet from jQuery you can use AJAX as suggest by the previous response.

You may find the following tutorials that I wrote regarding the use of Servlets, JSP, HTML, jQuery and AJAX useful:

[Step by step guide to setting up a J2EE web application](http://alextheedom.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/531/)

[Step 3: JSP template and tag libs](http://alextheedom.wordpress.com/j2ee/step-3-jsp-template-and-tag-libs/) and [Step 4: HTML5 and AJAX (jQuery) interface](http://alextheedom.wordpress.com/j2ee/step-4-html5-and-ajax-jquery-interface/) may be interesting to you.

In any event would you explain more clearly what functionality you are attempting to program. With more information I can give you a more specific response.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. jQuery runs in your clients browser, while the servlet is running in your serlvet container. AFAIK, there is no way to call jQuery from servlet. (as much as there is no way to load a page on your browser without you making the request).

What you *can* do is call your servlet from jQuery via an AJAX request(perhaps on web page load) and then handle the response, which can contain instructions for what to do next, like executing specific functions.